# returning index from JSON returned array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys I was wonder how you can return the index based on ID with the following.

```
$friends = '{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Paul",
         "id": "12000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Bonnie",
         "id": "120310"
      },
      {
         "name": "Melissa",
         "id": "120944"
      },
      {
         "name": "Simon",
         "id": "125930"
      },
      {
         "name": "Anthony",
         "id": "120605"
      },
      {
         "name": "David",
         "id": "120733"
     }
   ]
}';

$obj = json_decode($friends);
```

for example, I want to get print the name based on ID.  I've had a go at using array_search but it didn't like the structure of the array.  I will be using it inside a sql loop and passing the ID from the query to return the name string from the array.

```
print $obj->{'data'}[0]->{'name'}; 
//where 0 is returned index based on a defined ID.
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need PHP 5.3 in order to utilize the following closure and enhanced ternary operator (prints name if record is found; otherwise, prints 'No record found.'):

```
$findById = function($id) use ($friends) {
  foreach (json_decode($friends)->data as $friend) {
    if ($friend->id === $id) return $friend->name;
  }
  return;
};

echo $findById('125930') ?: 'No record found.';
```

Nice thing about this is that you can pass this callable around and it will remember the scope it was defined with. This means that you can pass any ID but the $friends array will always be available to the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The json_decode makes your variables into objects. To do a search, you could use:

```
// The extra true at the end makes it decode to associative arrays
$json = json_decode($friends, true);
findByName($json, 1234);

function findNameById($obj, $id) {
   foreach($obj as $o) {
      if($o['id'] == $id) return $o['name'];
   }
   return false;
}
```